nonparametric model for longitudinal data analysis
For the longitudinal data provided below, we have the following variables: the response variable 'y', the time variable 'week', 'grp' (with two levels: treatment and control), and 'subject'. My objective is to construct a model to evaluate the mean response at each week for each group, where the repeated measurements are assumed to have an unstructured correlation.
In SAS, normally, a model like the following would be used:
proc mixed data = df;
  class grp week;
  model y = grp week grp*week / ddfm = km;
  repeated week / subject type = un r;
run;

However, in the dataset, distribution of y at each time point is definitely not normally distributed. It is preferred to fit a nonparametric model for the purpose of estimating the difference between treatment and control at a specific time point. Is there a nonparametric method that is recommended for this purpose?
The data 'df' has the following format (actual data contains more observations):
subject       grp     week      y
1        1 treatment    1  0.2940239
2        1 treatment    3 -2.8439902
3        1 treatment    5 -0.8538669
4        2 treatment    1  0.3783948
5        2 treatment    5  0.4229227
6        2 treatment    1  0.9960380
7        3   control    3 -0.7838194
8        3   control    5  0.4189545
9        3   control    1  0.1854373
10       4   control    3  1.0416175
11       4   control    5  0.3229967
12       4   control    6  0.6163649


Rather than looking for a nonparametric solution, have you considered specifying a structured random effect (e.g. including an autoregressive term) rather than assuming a iid structure with respect to time? See https://www.fharrell.com/post/re/ for example
